# Notation Clarification

Tags: notation

Some functions (as an example) are written as $f(\theta;\mu,\sigma^2)$ and other occasions $f(\theta|\mu,\sigma^2)$ might be used. Can anyone clarify the difference in notation between using ';' and '|'?